# Avoid Loop in Slicing Operation

Tags: r, for-loop, conventions

I have the following code that I execute using a for loop. Is there a way to accomplish the same without a for loop?

```
first_list <- c(1,2,3, rep(1,5), rep(2,5), rep(3,5), rep(4,5))
print(first_list)
[1] 1  2  3  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2
[1] 3  3  3  3  3  4  4  4  4  4

breaks <- c(rep(1,3), rep(5,4))
values <- vector()
i <- 1
prev <- 1

for (n in breaks){
    values[i] <- sum(first_list[prev:sum(breaks[1:i])])
    i <- i + 1
    prev <- prev + n
}

print(values)
[1] 1   2   3   5   10   15   20
```

The purpose of the loop is to take the first three elements of a list, then add to that list the sum of the next four sets of 5.

Comment: It's just...some data. Lol. I will edit my question, and just merge the sample at the end into the original code.

Comment: Have you run your code? It resulted in `1  2  3 25 25 NA NA`

Comment: Hm, my code works, but I did not type it in correctly. I will fix it here.

Comment: Maybe `first_list <-c(1, 2, 3, rep(1:4, each=5))`

Comment: Yea, something like that. It was first_list that was wrong in my example: I fixed that, but my question still stands, and the code now runs.

Comment: `tapply(first_list, rep(1:length(breaks), breaks), sum)`

Comment: That works. If you post as an answer I will mark it as such. It won't let me accept my own answer for two days, plus I'd rather you get the credit.

Comment: Ok, done. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `tapply` for grouped operation

```
tapply(first_list, rep(1:length(breaks), breaks), sum)
```

or, preferably, using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
data.table(first_list, id=rep(1:length(breaks), breaks))[, sum(first_list), id]$V1
```

If you have to perform it on your data as in your original post

```
setDT(mydata)
mydata[, id:=rep(1:length(breaks), breaks),][, sum(Freq), by=id]
```